# Java Dynamic Casting using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have following code.

Parent Class:

```
class Parent{

        void a()
        {   
             if(// some logic to check whether child class is calling this method or some other class//)
             System.out.println("Child class is calling..")}
        }
```

Child Class :

```
class Child extends Parent{

        void b(){System.out.println(new Parent().a());}
}
```

Some Other Class :

```
 class Child1{

        void b(){System.out.println(new Parent().a());}
}
```

Here I am calling Parents a() method from one child class and from other class.

My question is what logic should i put in Parent's a method's if block so I can determine which class is calling this method .

I have some code but that is not working.Please help me what is wrong in this code.

```
if(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .loadClass(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName())
            .newInstance() instanceof Parent)
 {
           System.out.println("Child class is calling..")}
 }
```

Comment: @Dave : I want to restrict non-subclasses to access protected method.

Comment: @amicngh then make method private

Comment: @Ivan this is not the requirement .Subclasses can access my methods.

Comment: If some how I am able to cast dynamically to the same object type who is calling this method , that may work.

Comment: Any guess ? how can i do that ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "is not working."

Comment: this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .loadClass(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName())
            .newInstance() is returning generic object reference and then i am comparing it with Parent which is always giving true. it must return in case of subclass only.

Comment: @amicngh: This is _ridiculous_ overkill.  If you don't want other code in the package to use the method, then just don't write any code that refers to the method; you control all that code.  Using this kind of reflection is like using a flamethrower to kill a mosquito.  (If you're really that insistent, find an annotation-based solution.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am not intended to write the code in same package but if i leave the job and some other person comes he may write in the same package.

Comment: Then document it, or at worst use an annotation-based solution.  Identifying the "calling class," when it's even possible, imposes a huge performance penalty, it's ugly, it makes the code astronomically more confusing for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these options:

1. Move `Parent` to a different package and make `a()` protected. Since there are no other classes in the new package, only subclasses will be able to call the method.
2. You can try the stack trace approach but the information you seek isn't in the first frame - the first frame is where you call `new Throwable()`. Try frame 1 instead (that's the place where `a()` was called):

   ```
   ...getStackTrace()[1]...
   ```

   If you care about performance, you should cache this result.

That said, I'm wondering what the purpose of this code is. My gut feeling is that you're fixing a deeper problem by creating a brittle work around which will cause different pains. Maybe you should tell us what you want to achieve (the big picture).

Comment: Yes , I made it protected but the requirement is method a() of Parent class can be accessed by ONLY subclasses.so i have to put some check in if block.

Comment: How can you access `Parent.a()` from other classes when it's protected?

Comment: The classes in the same package can also access but i want to restrict  them .

Comment: Hm... you're right. I never use package access, so I completely missed that `protected` includes package access.

Comment: I have a protected  method a() in Parent class . My requirement is that only subclasses can access this method .subclass  have similar behavior as Parent class .I can do this by putting some check in method a() where i am checking which class is calling this method.

Comment: Add `new Throwable().printStackTrace()` before the `if` and you'll see that you're checking the wrong stack frame. Use `getStackTrace()[1]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out something like this, maybe thats what are you looking for

```
package pack;

class Parent {

    void a() {
        //my test
        try{
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            if (!e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName().equals("pack.Parent"))
                throw new RuntimeException("method can be invoked only in Parrent class");
        }

        //rest of methods body
        System.out.println("hello world");

    }

    public void b(){
        a();
    }

    //works here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Parent().a();
        new Parent().b();
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    //RuntimeException here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Parent().a();
        new Parent().b();
    }
}
class Child2{
    //RuntimeException here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Parent().a();
        new Parent().b();
    }
}
```

Forgot to mention that `b` method works fine in all classes. Hope thats what you wanted. Btw if you don't want RuntimeException then try `return` or throw other exception.